# How can I connect Jboss Fuse to a database?

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, jboss, jbossfuse, database

I would like to directly connect a database to Fuse. My goal is to save all messages received by one or more topics inside a database (MySQL, postgreSQL, MongoDB,...).

I don't need a failover database, basically I would "subscribe" a database to Topics and save all messages for future analysis.

What's the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

At a high level, the easiest thing to do would be setup a Camel route that consumes from the topic using the JMS component (or ActiveMQ if you're using that for your broker), and then write the message body into the Database using the JDBC Component. You could use PIDs to control the topic (or topics) that are consumed.

To create the JDBC connection you could either setup that up as part of your bundle containing the Camel Route (via blueprint/spring), or you could create a separate bundle that creates a JDBC connection/datasource via blueprint/spring and then exposes it as an OSGi Service for the camel route.